# How to stop notification panel from hiding?

Tags: java, android, notifications, remoteview

I want to make a notification with buttons. But after click on button- notification panel is hiding. What shall I do? 
I'm using this code to create my notification:

```
public class MyNotification extends Notification {
private Context ctx;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;



public MyNotification (Context ctx, int layaut_id) {
    super();
    this.ctx = ctx;
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
    CharSequence tickerText = "Shortcuts";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(ctx);
    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    notification.when = when;
    notification.tickerText = tickerText;
    notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), layaut_id);


    //set button listners
    setListeners(contentView);

    notification.contentView = contentView;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    CharSequence contentTitle = "From Shortcuts";
    mNotificationManager.notify(1387, notification);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setOnClickPendingIntent()` on buttons' views.
[setOnClickPendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent(int,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Answer (score 2):

Probably your notification is autocancelled when you click on it.
To disable this add:

```
builder.setAutoCancel(false);
```